# How to make main page with tab bar and some menu items in it?

Tags: android, menu, tabs, android-activity, tabbar

I'm trying to create an app, which consists of a login Screen and after the validation of credentials forwarding to Home Screen Activity.

In that Activity,  I want to place a tab bar (e.g. Home, User etc) and on a selected item to show some menu items (e.g @Home, "What's New", "Products", "About Us").

I'm stuck at coding that main page with tab bar (which I can) but, I don't know what control/object should I add and code. Any kind of help could be an improvement for me.

Answer (score 0):

For creating Attractive Tab / action menu items, you can try action bar sherlock library that nice to create Action bar and tab also.

Here is a [Link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for that, it comes with demo example